# How to make the column width of ag-grid responsive based on row data?

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

Columns in ag-grid:

```
columnsDefs = [
   {
    headerName: 'Name',
    field: 'name'
   },
   {
    headerName: 'Age',
    field: 'age'
   },
   {
    headerName: 'Description',
    field: 'description'
   } 
];
```

The characters length in description can vary. For example, some row might have just 10 characters and some row might have 50 characters.
If I set the column width then, if description has much longer length of characters then some of characters will not be shown.

api.sizeColumnsToFit() will scale the columns to fit the available width of the screen.
I wanted to achieve the column 'Description' width to be responsive based on the its row data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`columnApi`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-api/) method : `autoSizeColumns`

> **autoSizeColumn(colKey)**  Auto-sizes a column based on its contents.

Comment: Hi, I wanted to check and change the sorting (to different column) every time server call is made. OnGridReady is called before the data is bound so, I used onFirstDataRendered(). This works for first time when gridOption is initialize inside onInit() method. For next server call, onFirstDataRenfered() is not called. Which event is always called back after data is loaded on grid?

Comment: just call again `autoSize` once data is loaded.

Comment: Thanks, but in comment I am asking a different scenario of knowing any event callback when grid is loaded for first time and after other server call. Can you please help me  regarding this?

Answer (score 3):

To resize all the columns to the content width use:
`columnApi.autoSizeAllColumns()`. But, call this method on `firstDataRendered()` event. Also you can set `suppressColumnVirtualisation=true` if you have many columns.

**Explanation:**
`columnApi.autoSizeAllColumns()`  method resizes the columns to wrap the content width of each column. But, for the grid to know what is the content width, it first has to render the data. So, this method should be called on `firstDataRendered()` event. If the number of columns are more, then the columns which are behind the horizontal scrollbar does not render at once, because of lazy loading in ag-grid. So, `autoSizeAllColumns()` can not resize those columns. For that, lazy loading needs to be disabled using `suppressColumnVirtualisation=true` property of the grid.

Answer (score 1):

If you are coming to this discussion looking for the width of your table to adaptively increase or decrease based on the current width of the browser, here's how you do it in react:

```
let width = 100

const onFirstDataRendered = (params) => {
    params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
};

const onGridSizeChanged = (params) => {
    let columnCount = params.columnApi.columnModel.gridColumns.length
    width = params.clientWidth / columnCount
    params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
};


return (

    <div style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
        <div id="grid-wrapper" style={{ width: '100%', height: '263px' }}>
            <div
                id="myGrid"
                style={{
                    height: '100%',
                    width: '100%',
                }}
                className="ag-theme-alpine-dark"
            >
                <AgGridReact
                    defaultColDef={{ resizable: true }}
                    onFirstDataRendered={onFirstDataRendered}
                    onGridSizeChanged={onGridSizeChanged}
                    rowData={rowData}
                >
                    <AgGridColumn field="data" width={width}></AgGridColumn>
                    <AgGridColumn field={columnData[1].field} width={width}></AgGridColumn>
                    <AgGridColumn field={columnData[2].field} width={width}></AgGridColumn>
                </AgGridReact>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

};

Comment: This worked for me in Angular. Just made a few tweaks to adapt it to an Angular project.